# ¿Como acuatizar datos PHP MYSQLI?

Tags: php, mysqli

Este es el warning:

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\php\Proyectus1\editPerfil.php on line 105**

y este el codigo:

```
<?php               
session_start();        
?> 

<form action="" method ="post">
    </br></br>          

    <div class="content">           
        <div class="wrap">          
            <!---start-contact---->             
            <div class="section group">             
                <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                    <div class="contact-form">          
                        <?php           

                            include'conexion.php';          
                            $conexionbd = $contenido;
                            $consulfila="SELECT * FROM epicFilms.usuarios where nick like '".$_SESSION["nick"]."'";
                            $resulconsul=mysqli_query($conexionbd,$consulfila);             
                            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resulconsul))
                            {               
                                echo "<form method='POST'>
                                        <div>
                                            <span><label>Nick: </label></span>
                                            <span><input name='nick' value= '".$fila["nick"]."' type='text' class='textbox'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <span><label>Nombre: </label></span>
                                            <span><input name='nombre' value= '".$fila["nombre"]."' type='text' class='textbox'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <span><label>Apellidos: </label></span>
                                            <span><input name='apellido' value= '".$fila["apellidos"]."' type='text' class='textbox'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <span><label>Telefono: </label></span>
                                            <span><input name='tfno' value= '".$fila["telefono"]."' type='text' class='textbox'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <span><label>Mail: </label></span>
                                            <span><input name='correo' value= '".$fila["email"]."' type='text' class='textbox'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <span><label>Contraseña: </label></span>
                                            <span><input name='pass' value= '".$fila["contrasegna"]."' type='text' class='textbox'></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='Enviar'/>
                                        <input type='submit' name='borrar' value='Eliminar'>
                                    </form> ";          
                            }           
                        ?>  
                    </div>          
                </div>          
            </div>          
        </div>          
    </div>          

    <?php

        if(isset($_POST["enviar"]))
        {

            $insertfila="UPDATE epicFilms.usuarios SET nick = '".($_POST["nick"])."' where nick='".$_POST["nick"]."'";

            $resultado=$contenido->query($insertfila);
            echo$resultado;
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
            {
                echo"pene";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["borrar"]))
        {
            $insertfila="DELETE FROM usuarios where nick = '".$_POST["nick"]."'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($contenido,$insertfila);
        }

    mysqli_close($contenido); 
    ?>
```

Quiero actualizar los valores del formulario de arriba en la base de datos y mostrarlos actualizados

Comment: Te falta código, ¿Donde esta la conexión a la base de datos? ¿Probaste que estén llegando las variables que vienen por el formulario? Edita tu pregunta y agrega mas información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Esta comunidad es para ayudar, asesorar, pero no para hacer el trabajo por ti.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, formatea tu codigo como codigo, usando CTRL+K sobre el, y quitandolo de cita en bloque. solo pone el codigo que sea necesario

Comment: buenat tarde, según el tipo de error al momento de generar la conexión te devuelve un boolean y lo estas ingresando en una variable de otro tipo, revisa el return en la conexión, si nos brindas más información quizás te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: cual es la linea 105?